# fetching value from 'Dictionary<Int, [String]>.Values'

Tags: swift

```
var nameArrays = [
    1: ["twitter", "twitter", "", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter"],
    2: ["twitter", "twitter", "", "twitter", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "twitter", "", "", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter"]
]

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return nameArrays.keys.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nameArrays.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: IconCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellName, for: indexPath) as! IconCell

        let holdGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
        holdGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(longPress))
        holdGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(holdGesture)


        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
       // cell.appIcon.image = UIImage.init(named: nameArrays.values[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
        cell.appName.text = nameArrays.values[0][0]

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: cell.appName.text = nameArrays.values[0][0] is throwing an error Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<Int, [String]>.Values' with an index of type 'Int'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all your data source is not very efficient, you are encouraged to use a struct or class

However you can access the values considering the sections and preserving the order

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let key = nameArrays.keys.sorted()[section]
    return nameArrays[key]!.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: IconCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellName, for: indexPath) as! IconCell

 ...

    let key = nameArrays.keys.sorted()[indexPath.section]
    cell.appName.text = nameArrays[key]![indexPath.item]

...

}
```